# JSON data in not coming on FlstList in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I know how to populate jSON data on FlatList and I have done that , but now here , I am populating data in between button and table data , In componentDidMount i am calling both function , first table create and then JSON call , Table data I am taking from QRCode scan from another screen and taking here .

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ActivityIndicator, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import {Button, Text, DatePicker, Item, Picker, Input, 
       Textarea,FlatList} from 'native-base';

export default class OpenApplianceIssue extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
//      tableHead: ['Head', 'Head2', 'Head3', 'Head4'],
      tableData: [], qrData: '', loading: false, selectedPriority: '',
      selectedIssue: '', selectedReason: '', selectedTriedRestart: '',
      selectedPowerLED: '', selectedBurning: '', selectedNoise: '',
      AbcSdata : null, loading : true,
    }
    this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
  }

  setDate(newDate) {
  }

  _loadInitialState = async () => {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const qdata = navigation.getParam('data', 'NA').split(',');
    var len = qdata.length;
    const tData = [];
    console.log(len);
    for(let i=0; i<len; i++)
    {
        var data = qdata[i].split(':');
        const entry = []
        entry.push(`${data[0]}`);
        entry.push(`${data[1]}`);
        tData.push(entry);
    }
    this.setState({tableData: tData } );

    console.log(this.state.tableData);
    this.setState({loading: true});

  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done(); 
   // this.createViewGroup();
  }



  // componentDidMount() {
  //   this.createViewGroup();
  // }

  createViewGroup = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'http://Dsenze/userapi/sensor/viewsensor',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
           "password": 'admin',
            "username": 'admin',
            "startlimit":"0",
            "valuelimit":"10",
          }),
        }
      );

      const responseJson = await response.json();

      const { sensorData } = responseJson;

      this.setState({
        AbcSdata: sensorData,
        loading: false,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };


  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
  };
  keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id.toString();
  keyExtractor = ({ inventory }) => inventory.toString();

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.item}
      activeOpacity={0.4}
      onPress={() => {
        this.clickedItemText(item);
      }}>

      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Id {item.inventory}</Text>
      <Text>Inv {item.inventory}</Text>
      <Text>Sensor {item.inventory}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );







  onClickListener = (viewId) => {
    if(viewId == 'tag')
    {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('AddSensors');
    }}


  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    const AbcSdata = this.state;


    if(this.state.loading == false) {
        return ( <ActivityIndicator size='large' style={{height:80}} /> )
      }
      else {
            return (

            <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
                <Button full rounded light style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
                onPress={() => this.onClickListener('tag')}>
                    <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Add Sensors</Text>
                </Button>


                <View style={styles.container1}>
              {this.state.loading ? (
                <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

              ) :

              (
                <FlatList 
                AbcSdata={AbcSdata}
                  renderItem={this.renderItem}
                 keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}

                />
              )}
            </View>

          <View>
              <Text 
              style={{alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black'}} >
              Inventory Details
              </Text>

                <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff', padding:10,paddingBottom: 10}}>
                <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
                </Table>
                </View>
            </ScrollView>

            )
      }
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6 }
});
```

[image: I have to display data inbetween Add sensors and Inventory details]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code ..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
        import { View, Text, TextInput,   
        FooterTab,Button,TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, StyleSheet,
         ActivityIndicator ,Header,FlatList} from 'react-native';
         import {Icon} from 'native-base';
         import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
        import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
        import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class OpenApplianceIssue extends Component {


  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        AbcSdata: null,
      loading: true,
      search: '',
      tableData: [], qrData: '', selectedPriority: '',
      selectedIssue: '', selectedReason: '', selectedTriedRestart: '',
      selectedPowerLED: '', selectedBurning: '', selectedNoise: '',
    };
    this.setDate = this.setDate.bind(this);
}
setDate(newDate) {
}


_loadInitialState = async () => {
const { navigation } = this.props;
const qdata = navigation.getParam('data', 'NA').split(',');
var len = qdata.length;
const tData = [];
console.log(len);
for(let i=0; i<len; i++)
{
    var data = qdata[i].split(':');
    const entry = []
    entry.push(`${data[0]}`);
    entry.push(`${data[1]}`);
    tData.push(entry);
}
this.setState({tableData: tData } );

console.log(this.state.tableData);
this.setState({loading: true});

}

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done(); 
    this.createViewGroup();
  }

  createViewGroup = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'http:Dsenze/userapi/sensor/viewsensor',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
           "password": 'admin',
            "username": 'admin',
            "startlimit":"0",
            "valuelimit":"10",
          }),
        }
      );

      const responseJson = await response.json();

      const { sensorData } = responseJson;

      this.setState({
        AbcSdata: sensorData,
        loading: false,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };


  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
  };
  keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id.toString();
  keyExtractor = ({ inventory }) => inventory.toString();

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.item}
      activeOpacity={0.4}
      onPress={() => {
        this.clickedItemText(item);
      }}>

      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Id {item.id}</Text>
      <Text>Hospital Name {item.inventory}</Text>
      <Text>User {item.inventory}</Text>
      <Text>Date {item.inventory}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );



 onClickListener = (viewId) => {
    if(viewId == 'tag')
    {
      this.props.navigation.navigate('AddSensors');
    }}

    renderSeparator = () => {
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            height: 1,
            width: "86%",
            backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          }}
        />
      );
    };


  render() {
    const { loading, AbcSdata } = this.state;
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container1}>

        <TouchableOpacity full rounded light style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}
            onPress={() => this.onClickListener('tag')}>
                <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Add Sensors</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>


        </View>


        <View style={styles.container1}>
          {this.state.loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

          ) :

          (
            <FlatList 
              data={AbcSdata}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
             keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
             ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}

            />
          )}
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text 
          style={{alignSelf: 'center', fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'black'}} >
          Inventory Details
          </Text>

            <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff', padding:10,paddingBottom: 10}}>
            <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
            </Table>
            </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}   




const styles = StyleSheet.create(
    {
        container1:
        {
            flex: 1,
            alignItems: 'stretch',
            fontFamily: "vincHand",
            color: 'blue'
        },
        header_footer_style:{

          width: '100%', 
          height: 44, 
          backgroundColor: '#4169E1', 
          alignItems: 'center', 
          justifyContent: 'center',
          color:'#ffffff',


        },
        Progressbar:{
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            color: 'blue',

        },
        ListContainer :{
            borderColor: '#48BBEC',
            backgroundColor: '#000000',
            color:'red',
            alignSelf: 'stretch' ,
        },

        container2:
        {
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'stretch',
            paddingHorizontal: 15
        },

        inputBox:{
            width:300,
            borderColor: '#48BBEC',
            backgroundColor: '#F8F8FF',
            borderRadius:25,
            paddingHorizontal:16,
            fontSize:16,
            color:'#000000',
            marginVertical:10, 

        },
        button:{
            width:300,
            backgroundColor:'#4169E1',
            borderRadius:25,
            marginVertical:10,
            paddingVertical:16
        },

        buttonText:{
        fontSize:16,
        fontWeight:'500',
        color:'#ffffff',
        textAlign:'center'

        },
        textStyle:{
          fontSize:16,
        fontWeight:'500',
        color:'#ffffff',
        textAlign:'center'

        },

        item:
        {
            padding: 15
        },

        text:
        {
            fontSize: 18
        },
        button:{
            width:300,
            backgroundColor:'#4169E1',
            borderRadius:25,
            marginVertical:10,
            paddingVertical:16
        },
        buttonText:{
            fontSize:16,
            fontWeight:'500',
            color:'red',
            textAlign:'center'

            },
        separator:
        {
            height: 2,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.5)'
        },
        container: { flex: 1, padding: 16, paddingTop: 30, backgroundColor: '#fff' },
        head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
        text: { margin: 6 }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your FlatList component you are setting `AbcSdata={AbcSdata}`, while you should be setting the data prop:

```
<FlatList 
  data={AbcSdata}
  renderItem={this.renderItem}
  keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks , but data is not coming ,  and how can i call two function  on componentDidMount

componentDidMount() {
    this._loadInitialState().done(); 
   // this.createViewGroup();
  }

Answer (score 0):

It could be because *_loadInitialState* in your *componentDidMount* is an async call and table is getting rendered initially with no data. You could try passing in some prop to refresh once you have data. Also, in the code you put here, all calls to *createViewGroup*() are commented out but the definition is still there. Not a big problem but still very confusing for someone looking into your code.

Comment: Could you please help, please update in my question . Please

Comment: table data am taking from previous screen through QRCode and here on _loadInitialState am calling function and creating full table data

Comment: Putting a log in your render method should guide you towards what I am trying to say. Remeber that even _setState()_ is an async call. Verify that you have data before rendering the table, or re-render it once you have the data and you should be good to go. Also, given your context, __loadInitialState_ doesn't have to be an async function too.

Comment: in console i can see the data, but main problem is once am calling api one view is overlapping the screen.

Comment: Full code is there with api , could you please help